# Downloading Most Recent File On Server Via wget

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, wget

Good Afternoon All,

I'm trying to figure out how to download the most recent file from a server using wget on my Linux system. The files are 5-minute radar data so, the files increase by 5 minutes up to the most recent, i.e. 1930.grib2, 1935.grib2, 1940.grib2, etc.

Currently, I have the below code implemented in my bash script that downloads every file beginning at the top of every hour but, this is not an efficient way to get the most recent file:

```
HR=$(date +%H)
padtowidth=2
START=0
END=55
i=${START}

while [[ ${i} -le ${END} ]]
do

tau=$(printf "%0*d\n" $padtowidth ${i})

URL1=http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/fileServer/grib/nexrad/composite/unidata/files/${YMD}/Level_3_Composite_N0R_${YMD}_${HR}${tau}.grib2

wget -P ${HOMEDIR}${PATH1}${YMD}/${HR}Z/ -N ${URL1}

((i = i + 5))
done
```

Comment: Could you go into more detail?

Comment: There are extensive examples available, which is why I was rather terse.  There's the man page http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync and you can google rsync examples, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an index of all the files you could first download that and then parse it to find the most recent file.

If that is not possible you could count backwards from the current time (use `date +%M` in addition to `date +%H`) and stop if `wget` was able to get the file (e.g. if `wget` exits with `0`).

Hope it helps!

---

Example to parse the index:

```
filename=`wget -q -O - http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/grib/nexrad/composite/unidata/NEXRAD_Unidata_Reflectivity-20140501/files/catalog.html | grep '<a href=' | head -1 | sed -e 's/.*\(Level3_Composite_N0R_[0-9]*_[0-9]*.grib2\).*/\1/'`
```

This fetches the page and runs the first line containing a `<a href=` through a quick `sed` to extract the filename.

Comment: Hi mofoe, thanks! Could you post a link of parsing examples by any chance? I've tried but, no luck.

Comment: Well that strongly depends on the format of the index. Could you post the source of the page or an URL?

Comment: http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/grib/nexrad/composite/unidata/NEXRAD_Unidata_Reflectivity-20140501/files/catalog.html

Comment: you could try this: 

    filename=`wget -q -O - http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/grib/nexrad/composite/unidata/NEXRAD_Unidata_Reflectivity-20140501/files/catalog.html | grep '<a href=' | head -1 | sed -e 's/.*\(Level3_Composite_N0R_[0-9]*_[0-9]*.grib2\).*/\1/'``

Comment: Wow, thanks! So, I would run this right in the terminal or put it into my bash script?

Comment: please see updated answer. this is not perfect but works as a starter.

Comment: yeah place it in your script, i guess.

Comment: What you suggested gives me an error: "sed: -e expression #1, char 52: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS"

Comment: hmm... did you keep the `\( \)` around the pattern?

Comment: Updated my answer. There was a '`' to much at the end.

Comment: Ok, it turns out that I left out \ and \ ) so now it doesn't give me an error but now, nothing happens and there's no data that pops up in the terminal. Should this command be putting the filenames into a text file or something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51848/discussion-between-aaron-perry-and-mofoe)

Comment: the output of the command is being assigned to the variable $filename.  you can `echo` the variable to see its content like so: `echo $filename`

Answer (score 0):

I made a C++ console program to to this automatically. I will post the entire code below. Just use wget to capture the catalog file, then run this in the same directory and it will automatically create a BAT file that you can launch at will to download the latest file. I wrote this specifically for the Unidata THREDDS server so I know this is a good answer. Edit and *important note* : This is for the latest GOES-16 data, so you will have to play around with the substring values for different products.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


int main() 

{

// First, I open the catalog.html which was downloaded using wget, and put the entire file into a string.

ifstream inFile; // create instance
inFile.open("catalog.html"); // opens the file
stringstream strStream; // create stringstream
strStream << inFile.rdbuf();  //read the file
string str = strStream.str();  //str holds the content of the file

cout << str << endl;  // The string contains the entire catalog ... you can do anything with the string

// Now I will create the entire URL we need automatically by getting the base URL which is known (step 1 is : string "first")

string first= "http://thredds-test.unidata.ucar.edu/thredds/fileServer/satellite/goes16/GRB16/ABI/CONUS/Channel02/current/";

// The string "second" is the actual filename, since (to my knowledge) the filename in the HTML file never changes, but this must be watched in case it DOES change     in the future. I use the c++ substring function to extract it.

string second = str.substr(252784,76); 


// I then create a batch file and write "wget (base url + filename)" which can now automatically launch/download the latest GRIB2 file.

ofstream myfile2;
myfile2.open ("downloadGOESLatest.bat");
myfile2 << "wget ";
myfile2 << first;
myfile2 << second;
myfile2.close();


return 0;

}
```